# How to use ifelse inside map function in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, purrr

I am having problems with this `ifelse` sentence inside `map` function:

```
df<-list(mtcars,mtcars)
```

All I want to do is to organize each dataframe of this list this way:`slice(x,c(n(),2:(n()-1),1))`

```
map(df, ~   slice(.x,c(n(),2:(n()-1),1)))   # it works well.
```

But I cant do this inside ifelse when I set the condition `x$cyl == 4`:

```
map(df, ~   ifelse(sum(.x$cyl == 4) > 0, slice(.x,c(n(),2:(n()-1),1)), .x)) # The output is weird
```

I tried to do the same using lapply but its not working:

```
lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(sum(x$cyl == 4) > 0, slice(x,c(n(),2:(n()-1),1)),x))
```

Any help?

Comment: I saw your comments to Alec B for clarification, so I changed my answers based on the information you provided. The `map_if` function should do the trick.

Comment: `ifelse` is used when you are sure that all the arguments have the same length.  Here, `if/else` is better. According toe documentation `Value  - A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as test and data values from the values of yes or no.`   The 'test' is logical vector, which is correct, but is of length 1.  'yes' is a data.frame/tibble and not a vector and the number of rows are different than the 'no'.  You could wrap it in a `list` to get the length 1 for 'yes', 'no'.  But, I avoid using ifelse here

Answer (score 5):

We can use `map_if` to apply the function only when a condition is TRUE.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- list(mtcars,mtcars)

df2 <- map_if(df, .p = function(y) any(y$cyl == 4),
                  .f = ~slice(.x, c(n(), 2:(n()-1), 1)))
```

Comment: But is there any reason why `ifelse` doesn't work inside `map`??

Comment: @AnilGoyal I don't fully know the reasons. Probably because `ifelse` is expecting a vector.

Answer (score 3):

This approach checks each data.frame in the list for any rows where `cyl == 4`. If it meets that condition, your desired slice is returned. Otherwise, the data.frame is returned unchanged.

```
library(dplyr)


df<-list(mtcars,mtcars)



lapply(df, function(x) {
  if (any(x$cyl == 4)) {
    slice(x, c(n(), 2:(n()-1), 1)) 
    } else { 
      x 
    }
  })
```

If you strongly prefer `map`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df<-list(mtcars,mtcars)



map(df, ~ 
  if (any(.x$cyl == 4)) {
    slice(.x, c(n(), 2:(n()-1), 1)) 
    } else { 
      .x 
    }
  )
```

Comment: Thanks @Alec B . I understand what you say. But in my main code I need to use `ifelse`.

Comment: Why do you need to use `ifelse`? Is it because you also want to return rows where `$cyl != 4`?

Comment: I need to in each collumn `cyl` that has value `4`  the dataframe be reordenate using the `slice`function. If I have a dataframe that doesnt have the value 4 in `cyl`, nothing is done.  My reproducible example should have other dataframes without values `4` in its collumns. As soon as I can I will change my reproducible example.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand your problem now. Check my edited answer.